# Verifying that a function is Lipschitz

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

How can you prove the function $$f(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{k+|x|}$$ to be Lipschitz?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have 
\begin{align*}
|f(x)-f(y)|&=\left|\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}(-1)^k\left(\frac 1{k+|x|}-\frac 1{k+|y|}\right)\right|\\\
&=\left|\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}(-1)^k\frac{|x|-|y|}{(k+|x|)(k+|y|)}\right|\\\
&\leq \sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac{||x|-|y||}{(k+|x|)(k+|y|)}\\\
&\leq ||x|-|y||\cdot \sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac 1{k^2}\\\
&\leq |x-y|\cdot \sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac 1{k^2}.
\end{align*}